# Adding text to polyline google map

Tags: android

How to add text to multiple point on polyline for different coordinates.The polyline code is as follows:

```
PolylineOptions po = new PolylineOptions();
            for (HashMap<String, String> point : coords) {
                LatLng latlng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(map
                        .get("lat")), Double.parseDouble(map.get("long")));
                po.add(latlng);
                //po.add(new LatLng(27.3200,88.9711));
                po.width(5);
                po.color(0xFFFFFF00);
```